# How can I crossfade 2 tracks using the Spotify ios-streaming-sdk?

Tags: ios, swift, spotify, avaudioengine

I'd like to implement a crossfade feature for an iOS app where one track gradually fades out as the next track fades in to create a smooth transition.

Spotify does not allow the streaming of multiple tracks at once with the ios-streaming-sdk.

There should be a way to access the last 10 seconds of a track before it finishes playing, store it in a separate buffer, and mix it with the next track played.

Any guidance would be very appreciated.